# Inbound Email Handler

Tags: apex

Suppose I have sent an email through trigger to an email address.And that email address replies.So, can we get the body of mail to which receiver replied on reply in salesforce.

Comment: if you reply then all trailing mail would be there in body.

Comment: so how to get body of mail in apex class on reply to which receiver had replied.